# Source a file into R

Tags: r

In the book *A first course in statistical programming with R* by W. John Braun and Duncan J. Murdoch, there's an exercise asking :

> Use a text editor to create a file consisting of the line `randomdata <-
>   c(64, 38, 97, 88, 24, 14, 14, 104, 83)`. Save it to a file called
>   `randomdata`.

In my opinion, I've succeed this exercise. I used the software TextEdit, I wrote the command `randomdata <- c(64, 38, 97, 88, 24, 14, 14, 104, 83)` and I saved the file as `randomdata`. Did I do it right?

The second question, they ask the question :

> Source the file `randomdata` into R and confirm the `randomdata` vector
>   was created.

Could anyone be able to explain to me what is asked for? Some hints would be sufficient.

P.S. I'm using a Macbook Pro 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes you did it right.

2) You simply have to use `source` to execute all the codes lines that are in your file. In this case: `source('randomdata')` (assuming you created it in your working directory).

Note: it's better to name your file `randomdata.R`.

**Edit:**

- If you use TextEdit, save your file as **plain text** (TextEdit saves files in RTF by default)
- Save your file in your working directory (or if you don't, use its full path).

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I wrote `> source('randomdata.R')` and they indicated 
`Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'randomdata.R': No such file or directory`

Comment: Then your file is probably not in your working directory. Try to use the entire path of the file as an argument to `source`, e.g. `source('X:/Users/Law/Desktop/randomdata.R')`.

Comment: Could you tell me what the X means from the command `source('X:/Users/Law/Desktop/randomdata.R')`?

Comment: Oh just erase it, I was just trying to give you a random example path. I don't know Mac but I think that if for exemple your file is saved on the desktop, the path should be like `'/Users/Law/Desktop/randomdata.R'`.

Comment: I tried `> source("X:jg24/Documents/randomdata.R")`, but they indicated
`Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'X:jg24/Documents/randomdata.R': No such file or directory`

Comment: Same error if I indicate `source("/jg24/Documents/randomdata.R")`.

Comment: Is there a command on the terminal I could use the location of the file randomdata.R?

Comment: If your file is in Documents the path should be `'/Users/Law/Documents/randomdata.R'`, you should try this.

Comment: Same error for `source('/Users/Law/Documents/randomdata.R')`, `source('/j.g24/Law/Documents/randomdata.R')` and `source('/J.G24/Law/Documents/randomdata.R')`. What could I do now?

Comment: Sorry, if your user name is 'jg24' then the path is `'/Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata.R'`.

Comment: Now the error with `source('/Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata.R')` is `Error in source("/Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata.R") : 
  /Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata.R:1:2: unexpected input
1: {\
     ^`

Comment: Ok, there is {\ at the beginning of your file. It seems it's because TextEdit saves files in RTF by default. You have to save it as plain text: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/can-textedit-save-as-plain-text

Comment: Ok, my file is saved as plain text. However, when I insert the command `source('/Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata')` and I obtain the error `Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open file 'X:jg24/Documents/randomdata.R': No such file or directory`

Comment: I think you didn't use `source('/Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata')`. (Your error message says `cannot open file 'X:jg24/Documents/randomdata.R'`, it's not the same path.)

Comment: I'm not sure. How could I have a plain text if my file is .R?

Comment: The file extension doesn't matter. Name your plain text file 'randomdata.R', save it in your Documents folder and run `source('/Users/jg24/Documents/randomdata.R')`, and everything will work.

Comment: How do we know that the `randomdata` vector was created?

Comment: Type `randomdata` in your R console, and it should display the content of the vector: `[1]  64  38  97  88  24  14  14 104  83`

Comment: You are familiar with the language R. Thanks it works!